# In Postgres, can you update CITEXT value to a different casing?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Running a posgresql database.

I have a table with `CITEXT` columns for case-insensitivity. When I try to update a a `CITEXT` value to the same word in different casing it does not work. Postgres returns 1 row updated, as it targeted 1 row, but the value is not changed.

Eg

Table Schema - users

```
Column      | Type
___________________________

user_id     | PRIMARY KEY SERIAL
user_name   | CITEXT
age         | INT
```

example row:

```
user_id   | user_name   | age
_________________________________
1         | ayanaMi      | 99
```

SQL command:

```
UPDATE users SET user_name = 'Ayanami' WHERE user_id = 1
```

The above command turns `1 UPDATED`, but the casing does not change. I assume this is because postgres sees them as the same value.

The docs state:

> If you'd like to match case-sensitively, you can cast the operator's arguments to text.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/citext.html

I can force a case sensitive search by using `CAST` as such:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CAST(user_name AS TEXT) = `Ayanami`
```

[returns empty row]

Is there a way to force case sensitive updating?

Comment: Works for me: https://rextester.com/UXBQ87764

Comment: Ahhh thank you for this! Turns out we had a poorly thought out `TRIGGER` function that was intercepting the update!